# Error con superusuario en Django

Tags: python, django

- Buenas, estoy creando un proyecto en Django que tenga soporte para usuarios. Pues bien, cree el modelo Usuarios:

  ```
    class Usuarios(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        """
            Modelo creado para almacenamiento de todo tipo de usuarios
        """
        #* BASE ATTRS
        username = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
        email = models.EmailField()
        is_staff = models.BooleanField()

        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_names', 'last_names', 'age']
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

        #* NEW ATTRS

        first_names = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last_names = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        photo = models.ImageField()
        is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        current_status = models.CharField(default='bored',max_length=15)
        #* MANAGER
        objects = UsuariosManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.username}"

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Usuario'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios'
            unique_together = ['first_names', 'last_names']
  ```
- Implemente la respectiva configuracion en el `settings.py`:

  ```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Usuarios.Usuarios'
  ```
- El problema viene, cuando al crear otro modelo e intentar agregar registros desde el administrador, Django me arroja el siguiente error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- No consigo informacion al respecto en niguna parte, sin embargo, el error indica basicamente que el superusuario que estoy usando para usar el administrador no existe en la tabla `auth_model` (revise directamente en psql y efectivamente no existe). Supongo que sera algun error con la implementacion de los modelos para usuarios. Aqui esta el codigo del manager ...

  ```
    class UsuariosManager(BaseUserManager):
        def _create_user(self, username, password, email, is_staff, is_superuser, **kwargs):
            new_user = self.model(
                username = username,
                email = email,
                is_staff = is_staff,
                is_superuser = is_superuser,
                **kwargs
            )
            new_user.set_password(password)
            new_user.save(using=self.db)
            return new_user
        def create_superuser(self, username, password, email, **kwargs):
            return self._create_user(username, password, email, True, True, **kwargs)
        def create_user(self, username, password, email, **kwargs):
            return self._create_user(username, password, email, False, False, **kwargs)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto los campos que contiene la clase usuario son `username, email, is_staff, is_active, is_superuser, last_login, and date_joined`, entonces puedes usar `UserManager` de lo contrario si tu clase personalizada le agregas un campo adicional a estos, entonces deberás extender `BaseUserManager`.

Este ejemplo lo encontré en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) y hace referencia cuando defines un modelo de usuario personalizado, entonces `admin.py` debe de ser algo asi:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from customauth.models import Usuarios


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""

    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["email"]

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    disabled password hash display field.
    """

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["email", "password", "is_admin"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ["email", "is_admin"]
    list_filter = ["is_admin"]
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {"fields": ["email", "password"]}),
        ("Permissions", {"fields": ["is_admin"]}),
    ]
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ["wide"],
                "fields": ["email", "password1", "password2"],
            },
        ),
    ]
    search_fields = ["email"]
    ordering = ["email"]
    filter_horizontal = []


# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)

# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

en `settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "customauth.Usuarios" 
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
```

Comment: El error no tenia nada que ver con el administrador al final. Se trataba de un problema que ocurrió al hacer las migraciones. Lo solucione eliminando la base de datos y volviéndola a crear.